# Troubles changing template bg colour to Transparent

Tags: css

I'm having issues locating where in the css I have to modify to change a solid background colour to a transparent.

I have managed to assign a transparent background to the side menu but can't seem to modify the background color on the header menu the div id = GKTOP.

www.optusselect.com.au

Answer (score 0):

You had this style applied to it, therefore, it was being given a background image:

```
body.solidBg #gkHeader, body.solidBg .ie8mode #gkHeader {
   background: transparent url('../images/style2/header_bg_solid.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Therefore, you could fix this by changing the above to:

```
body.solidBg .ie8mode #gkHeader {
   background: transparent url('../images/style2/header_bg_solid.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**OR**

Simply overwrite it by adding this style to your CSS:

```
body.solidBg #gkHeader {
   background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fizzix that fixed it!  #legend